# Magento Ajax request - again

Tags: magento-1.9, ajax, request

My AjaxController

```
class AMBit_Product_AjaxController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action{

        public function getdataAction(){

            echo 'PRODUCTS IN THIS CATEGORY';
            echo 'temporarily removed content ....';


        }
}
```

and the code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    jQuery('.level1').on('mouseover',function(){

        var url="<?php Mage::getUrl('attributor/controller/getdata'); ?>";

        var catName = jQuery(this).find('span').text();

        console.log(url);

        jQuery('#prod').html(catName);

        jQuery.ajax({
            url: url,

            type: "POST",

            dataType: "JSON",

            data: catName,

            success: function(result){
                    jQuery("#prod").html(result,function(){
                        alert(result);
                        die();
                    });
            },
            error: function(result){
                console.log('no response !');
                },
        })
    })
 })
```

and "No response" ...
What  am I doing wrong ?

UPDATE (controller bit):

```
<frontend>
  <routers>
        <attributor>
          <use>standard</use>
          <args>
             <module>AMBit_Attributor</module>
             <frontName>attributor</frontName>
          </args>
        </attributor>
  </routers>
</frontend>
```

Comment: did you check the console what is ajax response?

Comment: responce: 404 :(  my module name AMBit, module name Attributor and the method getdata()

Comment: var url="<?php echo  Mage::getUrl('attributor/controller/getdata'); ?>" please try this

Comment: seems to be a bit better, but still 404 :( at least url look better :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this in ajax Url

```
var url="<?php echo $this->getUrl('attributor/ajax/getdata'); ?>"
```

Comment: Same as this: var url="<?php echo Mage::getUrl('attributor/controller/getdata'); ?>".
Returning the same url but it seem like it won't execute/find controller ...

Comment: You check your controller is called or not using Mage::log()?

Comment: check now controller error i think change the controller name.

Comment: there is controller name error so change your controller name in get url.

Comment: AAAAAA got it. My bad, wrong path indeed ;)

Comment: But now, I can't see any data in response ;)

Comment: Silly me ;) ajax wrongly formatted :)

Comment: okkk now u get solution?

Comment: Seems like yes, everything fine thank you :)